# Why won't my macro variable resolve?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro variable, `&myvar`, but it won't resolve when I try to put it in a data step variable.  Why won't it, and what can I do to fix this?

```
%let myvar=Hello, world;
data _null_;
  x='&myvar.';
  put x=;
run;
```

Comment: This is intended to be used to close questions as duplicate where the only problem is single/double quoting macro variables.  If someone else finds a good already existing one I'm happy to use that, but I could find one that didn't have other complexities to it that might have been confusing.

Comment: @NEOmen In some cases it is easier to create a 'dummy' question that has less complexity than other questions but nonetheless answers something that comes up frequently and then use it as a close-as-duplicate.  The 'dummy' question should still be technically a good question on its own (as this is) but isn't of course asked for the purpose of finding out information :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Macro variables in SAS won't resolve when they are in single quotes, `'&myvar'`.  They need to be in double quotes, `"&myvar"`, in order to resolve properly.

If you need to have single quotes and a resolved macro variable, you have a few options, but the simplest is:

```
%str(%'&myvar.%')
```

The `%'` inside of `%str` will place a single quote character (or apostrophe) in the text string by itself without causing it to be quoted.

```
data _null_;
  x="%str(%'&myvar.%')";
  put x=;
run;
```

or

```
%let myvar2 = %str(%'&myvar.%');
```

Comment: It is the outer quotes that determine whether macro expressions are resolved. If you are already surrounding the string with double quotes then the %STR() to protect the single quotes is not needed.  Just use "'&myvar'".  In a macro setting you can do it this way: %sysfunc(dequote("'&myvar''))

Comment: I think Joe was demonstrating how you can get the macro to resolve but also use single quotes. You might need this in an X or SYSTASK command.

Answer (score 1):

In SAS 9.4M6 or higher version, you can use `%tslit()` to achieve the same function.

```
%let myvar=Hello, world;
data _null_;
  x=%tslit(%superq(myvar));
  put x=;
run;

%put %tslit(%superq(myvar));

x=Hello, world
'Hello, world'
```

This is a macro pre-defined in SAS. Here is the documentation about it:
https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lebaseutilref&docsetTarget=n1phgnraoodvpln1bm941n44yq7q.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: Note that you don't need a macro. Just call `quote()` and pass it a single quote as the second argument. You can  use `%sysfunc()` to call it in pure macro code `%sysfunc(quote(%superq(myvar),%str(%')))`

Comment: @Tom Certainly possible, but seems more complicated than `%str(%'&myvar.%')` doesn't it?

Comment: @Joe Depends on whether the value to be quoted already contains quotes. And whether the macro quoting is going to cause trouble down the line.  The %TSLIT() macro is just an overly complicated way to generate the %sysfunc() call with convoluted logic to mimic the quote function's second argument.