# Can i use macro in the data step in sas?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I tried to use macro in data step to exclude rows that does not match the conditions, but it won't work. here is my code

```
%macro bbb(a);
data grade&a.;
set grade&a.;
if ID='schoolgrade&g.score1' then output;
run;
%mend;
%match(4)
```

so, i cannot use macro in the if statement? what else can i do?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't my macro variable resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946244/why-wont-my-macro-variable-resolve)

Comment: Also - next time, please include the error or whatever is telling you "this won't work" - otherwise it's not always possible to tell what your issue is!

Answer (score 1):

The macro processor will ignore strings bounded by single quote character. Use the double quote character instead.

Also what is the source of the macro variable `G`?  Or did you mean to reference the macro variable `A` which is the parameter define to the macro?

So this code

```
if ID="schoolgrade&a.score1" then output;
```

Will find the observations with ID value equal to "schoolgrade4score1".

Comment: the double quote worked! its that simple.. thank you so much!!!